# Error upon DataFrame.set_index : only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I display my DataFrame 'df_totals' I get the following output :

```
       Value    Month
0   -63585.86   Grand Total
```

Next, I'm trying to set the column Month as index. Therefore I do :

```
df_totals.set_index(['Month'], append=False, inplace=True)
```

In my code it crashed.
So I tried to reproduce outside to debug, but I don't reproduce...

However when I try to build a reduced test-case, I got no issue :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"Value": [-63585.86], "Month" : ["Grand Total"]})
df.set_index(['Month'], append=False, inplace=True)
display(df)
```

What is the best way to move forward on this analysis ?
Typically, I imagine there is a difference on the DataFrame definition at some point.

Also what means this error in this contexts ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to dump the pandas into a string:

```
print( "df = pd.DataFrame( %s )" % (str(df_totals.to_dict())) )
```

Thanks to this I was able to identify that my df was build as following :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame( {('Value',): {0: -63585.85999999999}, ('Month',): {0: 'Grand Total'}} )
```

And therefore the line

```
df[("Month",)]
```

Leads to a crash.